# cannot get stacktrace, source line # information from Mono .dll

Tags: c#, .net, mono, nullreferenceexception, xamarin-studio

I am running some `.NET` `.dll`s  on `Windows Server 2012`. The `.NET` assemblies were compiled from `C#` code on `OS X` with `Xamarin 4.0`. (yeah I know weird setup- but I am a game developer)
In general they run perfectly, but when it comes to inspecting `Exception` information, it's not so good. I am trying to pull info out of an `Exception` object, but it's all empty. I also tried copying the `.mdb` files along with the `.dll`s, and made sure I was building in `Debug`, and with debug symbols.
For example this code

```cs
log.Error (ex.ToString ());
var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
log.ErrorFormat ("st: {0}, frame: {1}, line: {2}", st.ToString (), frame.ToString (), line);
```

Generates output like this, just the method name, basically

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Mindlube.CD3.RandomMatchMaker.ProcessMatchQueue() [ThreadFiber-1] ERROR Mindlube.CD3.App [(null)] - st:    
at Mindlube.CD3.RandomMatchMaker.ProcessMatchQueue(), frame: ProcessMatchQueue 
at offset 927 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0, line: 0
```

Any suggestions for getting more detailed `Exception` information? Using `Visual Studio` on Windows is not currently an option because I don't have time to re-tool my entire dev environment. So don't say 'use VStudio' :)

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?  I have the same issue.  I set the build output to include full debug information (in Visual Studio) and also ran mono with --debug to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because .NET does not understand mdb files.

Unfortunately there is no tool to convert mdb files to pdb files, your only options would be to either write your own or execute your app using Mono on your Windows machine.